# Mi dropdownList no cambia de valor en llamada ajax pero en otras partes del js si lo hace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Mi problema es que no puedo cambiar el valor de mi dropdownlist de acuerdo a el valor de uno de los indice que me retorna mi llamada ajax.

Llamada ajax:

```
    var idTets = $('select[id$=DdlTest]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxxclase/xxxmetodo",
        data: '{idTest:"' + idTets + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $("input[id$=textWorkName]").val(result.d[0]);
            $("textArea[id$=textWorkTopic]").val(result.d[1]);


            if (result.d[2] == "Exam") {
                $("#MainContent_dropType option[value=0]").attr('selected', 'selected');
                //$("#MainContent_dropType").val(0);
            } else {
                $("#MainContent_dropType option[value=1]").attr('selected', 'selected');
                //$("#MainContent_dropType").val(1);
            }


            if (result.d[3] == "True") {
                $("input[type=checkbox]").addClass('checked', true);
            }
            //$("#MainContent_HfOnlineTestId").val(idTets);
            //setTimeout(eventClick, 1000);
            return;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Ya lo intente de esas dos formas pero no funcionario y de hecho lo intente con js puro a través de un for y tampoco funciono, lo raro es que si lo pongo en un document.ready ahí si me hace el cambio de valor.

Resultado del objecto result:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que es lo que devuelve exactamente tu llamada ajax? es decir, "result"

Comment: @MarioL ya actualice el post.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba seleccionar de esta forma

**Cambiando el atributo, a partir del index:**

```
 $('#MainContent_dropType > option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
```

**Cambiando el index del dropdown**

```
$('#MainContent_dropType').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
```

**Seleccionando la opción con dicho valor.**

```
$('#MainContent_dropType').val('valorEjemplo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seleccionar la opción del select a través del texto que contiene:

```
$('#MainContent_dropType option:contains("texto de la opción a seleccionar")').prop('selected',true);
```